# CSS @font-face rule not working in an HTML document that applies changes to d3.js code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, d3.js

I am fairly inexperienced with HTML, and the following document is all of my code. I'm trying to use the font requested, which is "Veteran Typewriter" and accessible as a ttf. However, it shows up in the console as "appearing" but won't actually show up as that font. Please help me understand why it doesn't physically change in the script? Any help is much appreciated!

(Please note: there are other curiosities in this code, and that is because it is incomplete. I deleted parts that might compromise the identities of people who are affected by this project. The problem itself is just the ttf/Veteran Typewriter font.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- setup code here based on http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/setup -->
<!-- more stuff from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jvoTV54nXw&t=921s -->
<!-- code base from: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642, http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/11550728, https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298 -->
<html>
 <meta charset = "utf-8">
 <!--<title>D3 Visualization></title>-->
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <!--Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--CSS Styling-->
   
 <style> 
  @font-face{
   font-family: "Veteran Typewriter";
   src: url(http://ff.cdn.1001fonts.net/v/e/veteran-typewriter.regular.ttf) format("truetype");
  } 

  #tags{
   font-family: "Veteran Typewriter", Palatino, serif;
  }
 </style>

 <body id="tags">
  <script type="text/javascript">  

   var w = 1000;
         var h = 1000;

         //var svgBody = d3.select('span[property="sioc:content"]').append("svg")
        var svgBody = d3.select("body").append("svg")
             .attr("width", w)
             .attr("height", h);

         var calibratedY = 125;

         //Contributors as nodes
         var contributors = [{title: "Sample", name: "Example", iy: calibratedY + 50, hl: "https://www.google.com/"}, 
             {title: "Sample", name: "Example", iy: calibratedY + 100, hl: "https://www.google.com/"}, 
             {title: "Sample", name: "Example", iy: calibratedY + 150, hl: "https://www.google.com/"}, 
             {title: "Sample", name: "Example", iy: calibratedY + 200, hl: "https://www.google.com/"}];


         var r = svgBody.selectAll(".rect").data(contributors)
          .enter()
          .append("g")
           .attr("class", "rect");
         r.append("rect")
          .attr("width", 500)
          .attr("height", 50)
          .style("fill", "#d16e23")
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .attr("x", 250)
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.iy});
   

   //Mouse behaviors
         //Mouseover - it turns slightly lighter, things in arc around it become lighter
         r.on("mouseover", function(d){
          d3.select(this).select('rect').transition()
           .duration(500)
           .style("fill", "#dd8a4b");          
         });

         r.on("mouseout", function(d){
          d3.select(this).select('rect').transition()
           .duration(500)
           .style("fill", "#d16e23");
         });

         r.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", 500)
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.iy+25})
    .style("font-size", "20px")
    .style('fill', 'white')
    .style('font-family', 'Veteran Typewriter')
    //.style('font-family', 'Helvetica')
    .text(function(d){return d.title});

   r.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", 500)
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.iy+40})
    .style("font-size", "15px")
    .style('fill', 'white')
    //.style('font-family', 'Helvetica')
    .text(function(d){return d.name});

   r.on("click", function(d){
                window.open(d.hl);
            });

   
         //Shape of the outer ring (tags)
         var arcGroup = svgBody.append("g").data(tags)
          .attr("transform", "translate(500,500)");
         
         var arcShape = d3.svg.arc()
          .innerRadius(425)
          .outerRadius(575)
          .startAngle(0)
          .endAngle(2*Math.PI);
         
         
         //https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193
         var pie = d3.layout.pie()
          .sort(null)
          .value(function(d){return 2*Math.PI/tags.length});

         var g = svgBody.selectAll(".arcGroup")
          .data(pie(tags))
          .enter().append("g")
           .attr("class", "arc");

         arcGroup.append("path")
          .attr("d", arcShape)
          .style("fill", "grey");

         g.append("text")
          .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate(" + arcShape.centroid(d) + ")"})
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d){return d.tag});


            
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at your console. You probably have a message like this: *"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"* The best alternative here is uploading the font to your server, and using a relative path.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply - Thank you so much for responding! The font needs to go onto a site where one can upload media, but to my knowledge, I'm not allowed to add the font directly to their server. Is there a way to work around this and just use the source link? The site is Scalar (through The Alliance for Networking Visual Culture), if that helps any.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. If you want, post a new question explaining the CORS issue.